# OpenCV Android Program Bottle-necked by Morphological Functions

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading, opencv

I have a function that performs erosion and dilation on a binary matrix:

```
void Detector::morphOps(Mat& binFrame) {
    Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
    Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(10, 10));

    erode(binFrame, binFrame, erodeElement);
    dilate(binFrame, binFrame, dilateElement);
    dilate(binFrame, binFrame, dilateElement);
}
```

This makes my program significantly more robust in detecting the objects I want to track. However, this code is a huge bottleneck for the rest of my program. I drop from 25-30 fps to <1 fps when the function is enabled. Is there something I can do to prevent it from killing my framerate (other than removing it from my program)? i.e. another opencv function that accomplishes the same task more efficiently?

I am also considering multithreading, but I am not sure how to implement it here as I am fairly new to android and opencv. The above code is native (jni) part of my program.

**EDIT**: Alternatives I have tried so far:

> morphologyEx() opening + closing - Doesn't perform as well because the dilate size needs to be larger than the erode size.
>
> morphologyEx() closing + dilate() - no significant performance boost on Android.
>
> changing MORPH_ELLIPSE to MORPH_RECT. I now get ~8fps, but this is still very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my Zenfone 2 and didn't have much performance issue, it got from 30fps to 23fps but I used 640x360 resolution.

Try reducing the image resolution:

```
javaCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(size.width, size.height);
```

You can also make global vars so not to have to initialize it all the time:

```
Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(10, 10));

void morphOps(Mat& binFrame) {
    erode(binFrame, binFrame, erodeElement);
    dilate(binFrame, binFrame, dilateElement);
    dilate(binFrame, binFrame, dilateElement);
}
```

Is your frame coming from javaCameraView ? it is also important how you pass the data from Java to C++, use like this:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
{
    _imgBgrTemp = inputFrame.rgba();
    jniFrame(_imgBgrTemp.nativeObj);
    return _imgBgrTemp;
}
```

.nativeObj passes the pointer without recopying the data.

And about threads, it might be a good idea but it is very complicated to make it work safelly, I also have a question about "OpenCV multithreading on Android".
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657849/opencv-multithreading-on-android)

At the time of writing this, there was no answer yet there, but you can follow with me.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at your question as well. My resolution is 640 x 480, but sometimes it starts at 1920 x 1080 and I don't know how to fix that. You mentioned making global vars.. does that mean setting img dimensions as global? I'm not sure how that will help unless I am understanding incorrectly.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention, I call morphOps() 7 or 8 times on different binary mat objects because I am looking for colored objects in different hsv thresholds. That is what slows me down, which is why I am considering parallel processing.

Comment: You should call:
javaCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(size.width, size.height);

before enabling the view, like this:

        javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        javaCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(size.width, size.height);
        javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        javaCameraView.enableView();
        javaCameraView.enableFpsMeter();

Comment: And about making the var global, is just a good practice in this case, because every time you initialize those vars, it consume some processing, and as they are always the same, it is a good idea to initialize them only once and reuse them every time you call the function without having to initialize them again

Comment: What kind of object are you looking for ? maybe there would be a better approach...

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the distance transform, you can emulate the morphological operations, especially those with a disk structuring element, and it runs much faster.

Instead of:

```
int closeDiam = 2 * closeRadius + 1;
Mat strel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(closeDiam, closeDiam));
Mat dst = new Mat();
Imgproc.morphologyEx(src, dst, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, strel);
```

try:

```
Mat negSrc = new Mat();
Core.bitwise_not(src, negSrc);
Mat negSrcDT = new Mat();
Imgproc.distanceTransform(negSrc, negSrcDT, Imgproc.CV_DIST_L2, Imgproc.CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE);
Mat dilated = new Mat();
Core.compare(negSrcDT, new Scalar(closeRadius), dilated, Core.CMP_LE);
Mat dilatedDT = new Mat();
Imgproc.distanceTransform(dilated, dilatedDT, Imgproc.CV_DIST_L2, Imgproc.CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE);
Mat dst = new Mat();
Core.compare(dilatedDT, new Scalar(closeRadius), dst, Core.CMP_GT);
```

The running time is about 1/3 whith radius=10, 1/8 whith radius=20, 1/11 whith radius=30, 1/21 with radius=40, and 1/29 with radius=50.

For some reason, the results of the two methods are not exactly equivalent (almost indiscernable for radius=10, but they differ more as radius increases). Conceptually though, they are identical: dilation+erosion.